# How to route data to a new page to fill a form using Vue and Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm looking for a solution for a feature I need to implement in my project. I have a data table with a certain amount of items where one of the columns has several action buttons. One of the buttons is an edit button.
What I need is to redirect the page to a certain route, for example "/edit", once the button is clicked, where there will be a form with some fields that need to be filled with the data from the selected item in the table.

At the moment I have the following:

Page with the Data Table

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="navQuestoes">
        <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
          <router-link to="/edit">
            <v-icon small class="mr-2">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
          </router-link>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    <v-card>
  <v-container>
<template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            headers: [
                { text: "Identificador", sortable: false, value: "id"},
                { text: "Domínio",  sortable: false, value: "domain"},
                { text: "Opções", sortable: false, value: "actions"},
            ],
            navQuestoes: [],
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/question`)
          .then((response)=>{
            this.navQuestoes=response.data
            console.log(this.navQuestoes);
          },(error) =>{
              console.log(error);
          });
    },
}
</script>
```

The following code is for the component with the form which fields I need to fill with the data coming from the first page with the data table.

```
<template>
  <v-form v-model="valid">
    <v-container>
          <v-text-field v-model="formData.id" label="Identificador"/>

          <v-text-field v-model="formData.domain" label="Domínio"/>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data() {    
      return{
        valid: false,
        formData:{
            id: '',
            domain: '',
          },
      }  
    }   
  }
</script>
```

I've started using the `<router-link>` which obviously redirects to the page whenever the icon is clicked and now I was thinking of using $emit to send the data over to the other page. Is this a good solution? How would I implement it now? Just to clarify, the data to be sent corresponds to the item in the "navQuestoes" array that matches the one in the table row where the icon was clicked. The data structures used need to be as shown because there's a lot more code already based on them.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways of doing this:

First, is to use Vuex to manipulate the array based in a global state.
Second, is to use the VueRouter like:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/ComponentWhichReceivesData/:id/:domain',
      components: {
        default: ComponentWhichReceivesData,
      },
      props: {
        // object mode, but it can be function mode
        default: { id: 1, domain: "example"},

      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I'd recommend you to use the VueX way, because you'll have more control manipulating data.